# Popup blocking to Login to Facebook

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Im trying to login to Facebook with Selenium Java but default window is opening with setting and accept All, help to handle this please, I have tried in different browsers but same issue.Thanks

Comment: Simulate to click "accept all" or load webdriver with existing browser profile (with already accepted cookies from fb).

Comment: Thanks!, I am new learner, I am not sure how to simulate accept all. I have tried through window handling, alerts, chrome options, i frame but nothing worked ...guide me please

Comment: I've inspected the login page, accepting cookies using selenium is easy. Managed on first try. Add your code including exception trace if any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This button has to be clicked

`<button value="1" class="_42ft _4jy0 _9o-t _4jy3 _4jy1 selected _51sy" data-cookiebanner="accept_button" data-testid="cookie-policy-dialog-accept-button" title="Přijmout vše" type="submit" id="u_0_p_s7">Přijmout vše</button>`

`id` and `class` values seems dynamic, a smart locator is needed.
`data-cookiebanner` and `data-testid` seems the same in every new session, so I will use this xpath:
`"//button[@data-cookiebanner='accept_button']"`

More about xpath: https://addwebsolution.com/blog/dynamic-xpath-selenium-webdriver-complete-guide

The rest of class is pretty much standard:

```
package selenium;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class FB {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        openFbAndAcceptCookies();
    }
    
    public static String workingFdir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    public static String chromedriverPath = workingFdir + "\\resources\\chromedriver.exe";  

    public static WebDriver startChromeDriver() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromedriverPath);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return driver;
    }
    
    public static void openFbAndAcceptCookies() {
        WebDriver driver = startChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@data-cookiebanner='accept_button']")).click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@data cookiebanner='accept_button']")).click();
```