# Locating elements with dynamic attributes

Tags: java, selenium, unit-testing, automated-tests

I ve been running some tests using selenium java and after every run element attributes in HTML change. I am testing a full web app from intellij ide using selenium 4.1.2 and mvn 3.8.5 while the web app .NET and Angular 13.
Any idea what is the cause of this problem ?

Comment: Locator is a part of your code, hardly to believe it changes without your edit. Or do you mean element attributes in the HTML source?

Comment: Yes I mean element attributes in the HTML code for ex: id :mat-option-17 changes to mat-option-19

Comment: You need to use dynamic xpaths, like in this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67070686/popup-blocking-to-login-to-facebook/67148086#67148086

Comment: Can you share URL with some steps you need to proceed?

Comment: @pburgr I dont think that s possible.

Comment: @pburgr can I please get a reference link where there is more detailed info about dynamic attributes

Comment: https://www.addwebsolution.com/blog/dynamic-xpath-selenium-webdriver-complete-guide, it's in the linked question too.

Comment: another one https://browsee.io/blog/strategies-to-handle-dynamic-web-elements-in-selenium/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can locate it by two mwthods 1) if part of the attribute value is static and the remaining value is dynamic lets say id=ABC123 and the 123 is dynamic and ABC is static try to use xpath with contains (@id,'ABC') or try locate the previous element which is static and use following method to traverse and locate this element